# What OG functionality can be triggered by building URLs?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

The OG README file states

> You may craft your own URLs which produce useful behavior. For example,
>    `node/add/group-content?gids_node[]=4` will add a select the group with node ID 4, in the node form. The prefixed entity can change to indicate other entity types allowing crafting the URL and you can have multiple variables, for example, `node/add/group-content?gids_node[]=4&gids_user[]=3&gids_group[]=5,6,7`. The above URL will select the group with node ID 4, and the group with user ID 3, and the groups with the unique group ID 5, 6 and 7.
>   Note that the actual entity of group ID 5, 6 and 7 can be any entity (e.g. nodes or users).

The above has several typographical errors, and I'm not sure if this is relevant for Drupal 7.

Does anyone have a detailed explanation of current URL crafting options for Organic Groups?